# Azure Search Document SDK not creating schema with right data type

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have created a schema of an `index` using the `python` API of the `azure-search-documents` package. I want all fields to be String except `invoice amount` and `invoice date`, which I want to be of type `double` and `date`.

```
name = index_name
fields = [
        SimpleField(name="InvoiceId", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, key=True),
        SearchableField(name="VendorName", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, sortable=True),
        SearchableField(name="Content", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, analyzer_name="en.lucene"),
        SearchableField(name="InvoiceDate", type=SearchFieldDataType.DateTimeOffset, filterable=True),
        SearchableField(name="InvoiceAmount", type=SearchFieldDataType.Double, filterable=True),
    
        ComplexField(name="Address", fields=[
            SearchableField(name="StreetAddress", type=SearchFieldDataType.String),
            SearchableField(name="City", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, facetable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True),
            SearchableField(name="StateProvince", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, facetable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True),
            SearchableField(name="PostalCode", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, facetable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True),
            SearchableField(name="Country", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, facetable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True),
        ])
    ]
cors_options = CorsOptions(allowed_origins=["*"], max_age_in_seconds=60)
scoring_profiles = []
```

When I executed the `Jupiter` cell and checked in the portal, the data type for the `invoice amount` and `invoice date` fields were `string` while I specified `Double` and `DateTimeOffset`. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.search.documents.indexes.models.searchablefield?view=azure-dotnet), `SearchableField Class` takes a **String** or `"Collection(String)"` field that can be searched.

To use `Double and DateTimeOffset` Datatype, you can define with `SimpleField`.

```py
# Define the index schema
fields = [
    SimpleField(name="Id", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, key=True),
    SimpleField(name="InvoiceDate", type=SearchFieldDataType.DateTimeOffset, filterable=True),
    SimpleField(name="InvoiceAmount", type=SearchFieldDataType.Double, filterable=True, searchable=True)
    # Add other fields as needed
]
```

With above index schema, I was able to create index with required data types:
[image]

For detailed example, you can check this [notebook](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-python-samples/blob/main/Quickstart/v11/azure-search-quickstart.ipynb).

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77749865/17322958

> IIRC SearchableField doesn't allow you to change the underlying type, it might be ignoring your input and always setting up the field as a string (or collection of strings).